# How to do function currying before c++11

Tags: c++

I have a function which have two arguments, and I want bind the 2nd argument to a value and get a new function object.

What I want is perfectly supported by std::bind in c++ 11, for example:

```
int my_func(int a, int b) {...}
auto bind_func = std::bind (my_func,_1, 555);
```

Or in python:

```
bind_func = functools.partial(my_func, b=555)
```

But I want to do it in C++03, I know boost can do it but I don't want invoke boost for this simple requirement.

Now I wrote my own template to do it, but it will be perfect if I can use standard library.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `std::bind2nd`?

Comment: In C++11 and above there is no need for std::bind. Simply use a lambda. If you don't want to use boost you could reimplement what they have done.

Comment: Maybe you can write your own functor, a class contains a function pointer and a vector of input parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

A functor is very easy to make.  And that's the only way of currying functions in pre 2011 c++.

Example:

```
struct my_func_functor  // choose a name
{
    int curry_;
    my_func_functor(int curry) : curry_(curry) {}
    int operator()(int a) { return my_func(a, curry_); }
};


// to use...
vector<int> v;

//...

// build the functor with the curry and let transform do the cooking...
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), my_func_functor(555));
```

You can of course store anything you want in the functor.  including references.  This is the same model used behind the scene by C++11's lambdas.  Instead of a capture clause, you have a constructor, and a structure to hold the data to pass along when the actual call is made through the `operator()`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I pretty sure this gonna work. But do you know if there is any other way if I don't want declare my own class? Because I will use this in several different modules, which cause I have to put this class class in a common place and let the other modules have dependency on that common place. And that my_func actually will use an 3rd party library. In a big project, invoke new module dependency is quite complex.

Comment: No, there are no other 'clean way'.  The only other way I know of in C++03 would be using global variables.  The lambdas, and even the basic code behind std::bind uses this technique.  All that boilerplate is cumbersome, I know, and it is the main reason the stl algorithms were greatly underused in c++ before c++11.  You can use this technique to declare sub-functions, or to create powerful functionality in dedicated modules, like sorting with options and the likes.  BUT.  boost has some lambdas support that you can use, if your app uses boost, you could use that, I guess, but they are limited